# Getting text from html - Casperjs and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, casperjs

I'm trying to get the text: sub1, sub2, sub3 of the li from example bellow with javascript while scraping with CasperJS. There are maybe 30 list elements.
 This is the string:

```
<li class="sb-option " onclick="javascript:s4.setState('5_43022,9_overview,239_t272‌​76,242_21',false);">‌​Sub 1</li>
<li class="sb-option " onclick="javascript:s4.setState('5_43022,9_overview,239_t272‌​78,242_21',false);">‌​Sub 2</li>
<li class="sb-option " onclick="javascript:s4.setState('5_43022,9_overview,239_t272‌​80,242_21',false);">‌​Sub 3</li>
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve. what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `casper.fetchText(selector)`
as per your requirement, you can use js array to store multiple html text. :)